# Run react-native init with yarn

Tags: node.js, react-native, yarnpkg

I have installed react-native on my Ubuntu 16.04. Now when I try to init a project it stucks at netwrok part like below

```
user-319@user-319:~/Dropbox/react-native-projects$ react-native init sadus 
This will walk you through creating a new React Native project in /home/user/Dropbox/react-native-projects/sadus
Installing react-native...
Consider installing yarn to make this faster: https://yarnpkg.com
loadDep:yargs -> network  / |##########---------------------------------------|
```

As suggested I tried to install yarn with `sudo npm install -g yarn` but it gets installed in `usr/local/lib` so when I run `react-native init ProjectName` it still asks me to install yarn.

So please help me

Answer (score 0):

apt-get update && apt-get upgrade 
 if yarn install erase 
 reboot

install yarn

https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/#linux-tab

creating a react native folder take some time